# Who shrank my fonts?

Tags: fonts

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10 and most of my screens have tiny fonts, including this forum. I've gone into System Settings and set my fonts to Noto Sans 16pt.  I've gone into the Firefox settings and also set them to 16pt. It hasn't helped. There's something else that is determining the font sizes. What is it and how can I change it?

Comment: Is it for all applications or just the browser? If it’s for everything, that sounds like an Accessibility item 

Comment: Are you sure you haven't [accidentally] changed your browser's zoom; eg. hitting 'Ctrl' + '-'

Comment: Are you using a hidpi monitor, if yes did you checked the display scaling?

Answer (score 0):

The not-very-obvious place where fonts are magnified or reduced is in System Settings->Display Configuration->Display and Monitor->Global Scale. Since this is three levels down in the menu structure, it's all too easy to miss it.